# trigger firing based on date difference with current date

Tags: zabbix

I have an item which is a trap that is returning an Epoch time like so:

```
1539302400
```

This represents as `2018-10-11 20:00:00`

What I want to be able to do is have a zabbix trigger that if the value on that Epoch time is less than 32 days from the current date to send an alert.

So if the current date is `2018-10-01 20:00:00` I want the trigger to fire, but if the current date is `2018-09-01 20:00:00` then the trigger would not fire.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fuzzytime()` [trigger function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) like so:

```
fuzzytime(32d)=1
```